# Subsequences of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

We're going to be doing a math test soon and I'm unsure about one of the questions regarding whether something is a subsequence of a sequence (here's a link to the whole question: http://puu.sh/cDc6L/8832f2d6be.png ... its in Czech, the question is "Which of these are subsequences of..."
Ill also type out the sequence: $((-1)^n * \ln n)^\infty_{n=1}$
and the subsequences:

> $((-1)^n)^\infty_{n=1}$
>
> $(\ln n)^∞_{n=1}$
>
> $(\ln(2n+1))^∞_{n=1}$
>
> $(\ln(4n))^∞_{n=1}$

Thank you

Comment: What do you think ? What have you done ?

Comment: Note that since $(-1)^{4n}=1$, the fourth is obtained by taking every $4$-th term of the original sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing out the terms of the original sequence:

$$
- \ln 1, \ln 2, - \ln 3, \ln 4, - \ln 5, \ln 6, \dots
$$

Now try writing out the candidate subsequences:

$$
-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, \dots
$$

$$
\ln 1, \ln 2, \ln 3, \ln 4, \ln 5, \ln 6, \dots
$$

$$
\ln 3, \ln 5, \ln 7, \dots
$$

$$
\ln 4, \ln 8, \ln 12, \dots
$$

Which of these appear, *in their entirety*, within the original sequence?

(and can you make an argument why this will apply to the entire subsequence, and not just the finite number of terms I've written out?)

Comment: Thank you ! That made it much simpler... Only the 4th one, right?

Comment: Yep, only the fourth one. Though to really finish this, you should construct an argument showing this (see André Nicolas' comment)